# Replace selected text while typing in Intellij editor

Tags: intellij-idea, editor

I am using

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.2 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-213.6777.52, built on January 27, 2022        
Runtime version: 11.0.13+7-b1751.25 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 11.6.5
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 8
Non-Bundled Plugins:
    com.intellij.plugins.watcher (213.6461.19)
    com.intellij.guice (213.6461.21)
    aws.toolkit (1.45-213)
    AWSCloudFormation (213.5744.122)

Kotlin: 213-1.5.10-release-949-IJ6777.52
```

When in the editor, I select text and start typing but the selected text is appended to what i am typing or wrapped.  I would like to replace the selected text but cannot find a setting to do so.

I found [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205971484-Typing-does-not-replace-selected-text-in-IntelliJ), but I do not have `ideaVim` installed.

> What setting needs to be changed so that editor selected text is
> REPLACED when typing?

Comment: Works out of the box, there is no setting for that. Selected text is always replaced when you start typing in IntelliJ IDEA editor. See if you can reproduce it with the default settings and no third-party plug-ins.

Comment: @CrazyCoder  Quotation mark is an example that consistently wraps around the selected text I wish to replace.  I have to delete the text before I type a quotation mark.

Comment: @CrazyCoder  I think I want to uncheck `Surround selection on typing quote or brace` for this specific question, but the insert pair quote is also something I will disable.  Thank you - please move to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following options may affect the behavior of the editor when working with selection:

- Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | General | Smart Keys | **Surround selection on typing quote or brace**
- Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | General | Smart Keys | **Insert pair quote**